# HTTPS using jmeter is not working and getting 403 error

Tags: jmeter

I am load testing an HTTPS service using jmeter.

**It works well by using following curl on a linux box:**

> curl -k -v -HContent-Type:application/json
>   -HauthToken:abcdefghijkla995e2f9-6cba-46e7-8b08-a7ffb67ca95d20150416163318
>   -Hsystem_name:testingsystemname -X POST --data-binary '{"deviceId":"1","cookieId":null,"emailId":"jmetertest@gmail.com"}'
>   https://localhost:9443/service/push/datacheck

How do I use **jmeter** to hit the request for load testing.

I was putting the authToken and system_name under 'send parameters with request' but it did not work and i keep on getting a 403 error.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to your Test Plan and configure it to send the following headers:

1. authToken=abcdefghijkla995e2f9-6cba-46e7-8b08-a7ffb67ca95d20150416163318
2. system_name=testingsystemname

   [image: HTTP Header Manager]

For sending JSON switch [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to "Body Data" tab and put it there.